# Qt QLine class extension

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

I am trying to extend QLine class to include a color attribute. I used QCreator to create the code for the new class QLineColor and I just added the attribute char color=0 in the public data. Here is the code generated by QCreator.

UPDATE: Modified according to response about QObject. but now I am getting some other errors:

```
/home/james/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/include/QtCore/qobject.h:309: error:
 ‘QObject::QObject(const QObject&)’ is private
within this context
and it lists several qt/include directories
```

File:QLineColor.h

```
#ifndef QLINECOLOR_H
#define QLINECOLOR_H

#include <QLine>
#include <QObject>

class QLineColor : public QObject, public QLine
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QLineColor(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, char color);
    char color;


};

#endif // QLINECOLOR_H
```

File:qlinecolor.cpp

```
#include "qlinecolor.h"

QLineColor::QLineColor(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, char color) :
    QLine(x1, y1, x2, y2)
{
    color = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QLine doesn't derive from QObject. Therefore Q_OBJECT etc. are all undefined.

```
#include <QLine>
class QLineColor : public QLine
{
    QLineColor();
    char color;
};
```

should work.

Answer (score 2):

To include `Q_OBJECT` macro inside class definition, the class must inherit `QObject`:

```
#include <QLine>
#include <QObject>

class QLineColor : public QObject, public QLine
{
    Q_OBJECT
```

**EDIT**

You need to include `Q_OBJECT` macro if you use signal and slots mechanism with your class. If you don't use signal and slots, you can omit `Q_OBJECT`.